# Evaluate $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n}\frac{1}{6^i}$

Tags: summation, geometric-progressions

I'm asked to evaluate: $$\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n}\frac{1}{6^i}$$

Since it's a geometric series, I got $\dfrac{1-\frac{1}{6^n}}{\frac56}$ but I think it could be wrong.

Comment: Did you check some simple cases?

Comment: @Henry yes I do mean the ∑ sign

Comment: @Did What do you mean by some simple cases? I firstly wrote out the series, 1 + 1/6^1 + 1/6^2

Comment: Dunno... N=0 perhaps? Or N=1? Or even, let us be foolishly daring, N=2?

Comment: @Did for N=0 I get 0 for N=1 I get 7/6

Comment: Right, and do these correspond to the formula (1-1/6^N)/(5/6) that you suggest?